# Can it take a singular or plural verb?

Tags: grammar

I'm confused with the use of "an abundance of something" in the following sentences. Can it take a singular or plural verb? Are both correct?

> 1. There is an abundance of shops.
> 2. There are an abundance of shops.

Comment: **an abundance** (singular) → **is** (singular)

Comment: Thanks, Jason Brassford. In the sentence "There are a lot of books", Isn't "a lot" singular?

Comment: "A lot" can be singular or plural, depending on the count/non-count nature of the noun: There is a lot of water on the floor, there are a lot of flies in the kitchen.

Comment: @Theinlwin Also, if *lot* is used in the sense of *box*, then it actually would be *there is a lot of books*, although that's not the way *lot* is normally interpreted.